# Deprecation warning with "spring rspec" but not "rspec"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, rspec

When I run spec via bundler, I get no errors...

```
bundle exec rspec -fd spec/controllers/blah.rb
```

But when I run it via the binstub to use spring, I get lots of these errors:

```
./bin/rspec -fd spec/controllers/blah.rb

DEPRECATION WARNING: `serialized_attributes` is deprecated without replacement, and will be removed in Rails 5.0.
```

Why is this?

I have tried stopping and starting; no effect.

In `config/environments/test.rb` I have this:

```
# Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
```

---

For reference...

```
$ bundle list | grep -E '(rspec|spring)'
  * rspec-core (3.0.4)
  * rspec-expectations (3.0.4)
  * rspec-mocks (3.0.4)
  * rspec-rails (3.0.2)
  * rspec-support (3.0.4)
  * spring (1.7.2)
  * spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)
```

---

As requested, my `./bin/rspec` file...

```
$ cat ./bin/rspec
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
# frozen_string_literal: true
#
# This file was generated by Bundler.
#
# The application 'rspec' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require "pathname"
ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

load Gem.bin_path("rspec-core", "rspec")
```

Comment: What is the contents of `./bin/rspec`?

Comment: `--color --require spec_helper`  (stupid SO comment formatting!)

Comment: I've tried using `--deprecation-out /dev/null` but no luck...

Comment: Added gem versions...

Comment: Please could you post the actual contents of `./bin/rspec` in your post? It's clearly going to contain more than just `--color --require spec_helper`...

Comment: Sorry, @TomLord - my mistake.. misread it as `.rspec`, not `./bin/rspec`... Added

Comment: This is the file generated by the binstubs command - I've not changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Well one possible *fix* is to change this:

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
```

to

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :silence
```

However this does not answer why its suppressed for rspec, not not via spring?!